# django social auth and email auth

Tags: django, authentication, django-socialauth

I'm finding way that auth with django or facebook.

Django social auth is for facebook auth. But I need Email Auth, to.

(In my site, User can select auth with email or auth with facebook )

Is it possible? if it is possible, how can I make it?

Is there any sample code?

Comment: Look [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) it has both types of authentication methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:
[Log in with email address in Django](http://justcramer.com/2008/08/23/logging-in-with-email-addresses-in-django/)

Also this: [Django email auth](http://www.micahcarrick.com/django-email-authentication.html)